# How to hide hyperlink when moving mouse to link?

Tags: html, hide

I have code this:

```
<a href="http://google.com" ><img border="0" src="http://i.imgur.com/123.png" /></a>
```

So, How to hide hyperlink when moving mouse to link ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: Do you actually want to hide it when user is trying to click it..?

Comment: What is the point of a link if the user cannot click it, because it's no longer there on a mouse-over?

Comment: You want to hide the URL from the user? That doesn't sound sketchy

Comment: Or are you asking how to hide the **underline** of the link on the mouse-over?

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following in your css will do.

```
a:hover{
 visibility:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a:hover{
   visibility:hidden;
}
```

or

```
a:hover{
   opacity: 0;
}
```

or

```
a:hover{
   display: none;
}
```

Comment: Hi, when I add first code, link in browser not be shown but image was twinkling continually

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to punt with a complete guess here, but what I think you're asking is how to remove the **underline** from a link on mouse-over?

If that is a correct guess, then try this...

```
<a href="http://google.com" onmouseover="this.style.textDecoration='none'"
  onmouseout="this.style.textDecoration=''">...</a>
```

If this is something you want all ALL links within your page, then use the following CSS (and don't bother with the `onmouseover` or `onmouseout` code above)...

```
a:hover { text-decoration: none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to hide the `href` of HTML `a` tag, You do it like this , something that google do it for tracking in search result.

Also all the URLs on Google search results pages are "rewritten" upon mouse down event using the following javascript function.

```
function rwt(el,ct,cd,sg) {
el.href="/url?sa=t&ct="+escape(ct)+"&cd="+....
return true;
}
```

and set `onmousedown="return rwt(this,'res','1','')"` for your HTML `a` tag.

To test it in google using Firefox, just search for something on Google and then before clicking on a search result, right click on the URL and then click on "copy link location".

---

**DEMO Here : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3dSQa/)**